# Reduce size of JSON produced by System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, system.text.json

I am building a web app using Blazor WASM with a .NET backend. We are hitting a problem, where the json returned from the API is bigger than we want/need it to be. Maybe the right solution is to write custom serializer methods for each action on the controllers, but was hoping there was a simpler way of reducing the size of the serialized json without having to do that.

Consider the following classes:

```
public class Comment
  {
    [Key]
    public int CommentID { get; set; }

    public int FilterSelectionGroupID { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Comments")]
    public virtual FilterSelectionGroup FilterSelectionGroup { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The comment should not be empty.")]
    public string Comment { get; set; }
  }

public class FilterSelectionGroup
  {
    [Key]
    public int FilterSelectionGroupID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("FilterSelectionGroupID")]
    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("FilterSelectionGroupID")]
    public virtual ICollection<FilterSelectionGroupValueAssigment> FilterSelectionGroupValueAssigments { get; set; }
  }
```

I get them from the database using EFCore and then return the data from the controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromQuery] PaginationFilter pagination)
{
    var validPagination = new PaginationFilter(pagination.PageNumber, pagination.PageSize);

    var items = await _powerBICommentService.Get(validPagination);
    return Ok(new PagedResponse<Comment>(items.Data, validPagination.PageNumber, validPagination.PageSize, items.TotalRecords));
}
```

Finally the resulting json is something like this. Note that the comments get repeated in the FilterSelectionGroup (it doesn't cause a loop because I have set `o.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles` on Startup.cs).

This gets even worse, because in the real model, there are other classes that have references to the comments, so I can have the comments repeating 3 or 4 times in the final structure.

What I'd like would be of a way to say if class Comment has been serialized on "level 1" then don't serialized it again.

```
"data": [
    {
      "CommentID": 1,
      "FilterSelectionGroupID": 1,
      "FilterSelectionGroup": {
        "FilterSelectionGroupID": 1,
        "Comments": [
          null,
          {
            "CommentID": 2,
            "FilterSelectionGroupID": 1,
            "FilterSelectionGroup": null
          },
          {
            "CommentID": 3,
            "FilterSelectionGroupID": 1,
            "FilterSelectionGroup": null
          }]
       }
    },
    {
      "CommentID": 2,
      "FilterSelectionGroupID": 1,
      "FilterSelectionGroup": {
        "FilterSelectionGroupID": 1,
        "Comments": [
          {
            "CommentID": 1,
            "FilterSelectionGroupID": 1,
            "FilterSelectionGroup": null
          },
          null,
          {
            "CommentID": 3,
            "FilterSelectionGroupID": 1,
            "FilterSelectionGroup": null
          }]
       }
    },
    {
      "CommentID": 3,
      "FilterSelectionGroupID": 1,
      "FilterSelectionGroup": {
        "FilterSelectionGroupID": 1,
        "Comments": [
          {
            "CommentID": 1,
            "FilterSelectionGroupID": 1,
            "FilterSelectionGroup": null
          },
          {
            "CommentID": 2,
            "FilterSelectionGroupID": 1,
            "FilterSelectionGroup": null
          },
          null
        ]
       }
   }
]
```

Thanks for any help/suggestions.

Comment: I will send the items.Data to a function that does the 'reducing' like return Ok(new PagedResponse<Comment>(REDUCE_ME(items.Data), validPagination.PageNumber, validPagination.PageSize, items.TotalRecords));

Comment: If you always wanted to exclude the `Comments` collection, you could mark it with `[JsonIgnore]`, as shown in the docs: [How to ignore properties with System.Text.Json | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-ignore-properties?pivots=dotnet-6-0)

Comment: @RichardDeeming I only want to exclude (other) comments when the "main" object I'm returning is comments

Comment: @JoaoLeal Do you have [lazy loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/lazy) enabled? If not, is there some code that's forcibly loading the related entities? Otherwise, if you don't `.Include` the navigation property, it should be `null`.

Comment: @RichardDeeming In this case I'm eagerly loading (`.Include`) the FilterSelectionGroup because I need some properties from there (not in the example for simplicity)

Comment: Add [Response compression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/response-compression?view=aspnetcore-6.0), reduce the fields name i.e. `FilterSelectionGroupID` to `GrpID`, [remove null values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions.ignorenullvalues?view=net-6.0)

Comment: @JoaoLeal Strange - I'd have thought the `Comments` collection would still be `null` unless you had a `.ThenInclude(g => g.Comments)` as well. Maybe it's populating the collection with the comments that have already been loaded, which might explain the `null`  values within the collection.

Comment: @RichardDeeming - yes it does exactly that. I have a paged response, so if the page size is 5, in the FilterSelectionGroup I only get 5 comments, if it's 10 I get 10 (if you count the `null` as on of those)

Comment: @JoaoLeal I suspect you might need to project the items to an anonymous type or DTO; even using `.AsNoTracking()` doesn't seem to prevent the collection from being populated.